# Unable to play mp4 Videos in Angular after passing it as JSON files from assets/videos

Tags: angular, typescript, video

This is my html template where I am displaying the data to the view:

```
<mat-grid-list cols="2" rowHeight="550px">
<mat-grid-tile *ngFor='let video of videos'>
<video controls (click)="toggleVideo()" #videoPlayer width="640" height="400" allow="autoplay">
<source src="{{video.videoUrl}}" type="video/mp4" />
  Browser not supported
</video>
    <mat-grid-tile-header>
    {{ video.pageTitle }}
    </mat-grid-tile-header>
    <mat-grid-tile-footer style="background-color: black">
     <span>Posted on -  {{ video.postDate }}</span>
    </mat-grid-tile-footer>
  </mat-grid-tile>
</mat-grid-list>
```

This is my TS component where I decide to play the video or pause the video:

```
@ViewChild('videoplayer') private videoplayer: any;
toggleVideo(event: any) {
    this.videoplayer.nativeElement.play();
    // this.videoplayer.nativeElement.pause();}
```

This is the JSON file I am passing to the template for the view:

```
const posts =
 [
     {
       videoId: "kode5476",
       pageTitle: "The man of my dream",
       postDate: "Mar 18, 2019",
       videoUrl: "../src/assets/videos/theweekend.mp4"

     },
     {
       videoId: "jkde5498",
       pageTitle: "The woman who makes the money",
       postDate: "June 23, 2018",
       videoUrl: "../src/assets/videos/daniel.mp4"
     },
     {
       videoId: "jkde`enter code here`5498",
       pageTitle: "The woman who makes the money",
       postDate: "November 17, 2000",
       videoUrl: "../src/assets/videos/theweekend.mp4"
     }];
```

Comment: are you getting any error in console?

Comment: Yes I am getting this error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'nativeElement' of undefined`... telling me it is coming from my component.ts

Comment: @taiwosunday check `if(this.videoplayer) {  this.videoplayer.nativeElement.play();}` you call nativeElement befare it will create  that why check first after that call and why you are call `click ` on video

Comment: I made a mistake in my html template with @ViewChild in my ts, which is misspell of #videoPlayer. now I have corrected it yet it is not playing or refuse to click either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally solved it after 5 days of trying different methods. The problem was locating my videos in assets through the src folder instead of referencing the asset folder direct. So I finally did it like this and it work fine.So I had to edit my JSON file to look like this:

```
 const posts = [
{
  videoId: "fade3536",
  pageTitle: "A woman who build her home",
  postDate: "June 18, 2017",
  videoUrl: "assets/videos/daniel.mp4",
  Type: "video/mp4"

},
 {
   videoId: "kode5476",
   pageTitle: "The man of my dream",
   postDate: "Mar 18, 2019",
   videoUrl: "assets/videos/theweekend.mp4",
   Type: "video/mp4"

 },
   {
   videoId: "jkde5498",
   pageTitle: "The woman who makes the money",
   postDate: "June 23, 2018",
   videoUrl: "assets/videos/twws.mp4",
   Type: "video/mp4"
   },
    {
      videoId: "jkde5498",
      pageTitle: "The woman who makes the money",
      postDate: "November 17, 2000",
      videoUrl: "assets/videos/daniel.mp4",
      Type: "video/mp4"
    }
```

];

There was no need for me to add nativeElement in order to play or pause the video because the video tag already come with those features.

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot to reference the element of the video in the ts component

Instead of

```
@ViewChild('videoplayer') private videoplayer: any; toggleVideo(event: any) { this.videoplayer.nativeElement.play(); // this.videoplayer.nativeElement.pause();}
```

Try

```
@ViewChild('videoplayer') private videoplayer: ElementRef; toggleVideo(event: any) { this.videoplayer.nativeElement.play(); // this.videoplayer.nativeElement.pause();}
```

Comment: ...it is not working even when I added ElementRef. my console is showing `
daniel.mp4:1 GET http://localhost:4200/src/assets/videos/daniel.mp4 404 (Not Found)
` . I am passing the video json from my restful api

Comment: Does the video title appear? Or anything else related to the video?

Comment: everything appears.. the title, the date and the video...just that the video is not displaying the proper video and not playing even when I allowed autoplay in my video tag

Comment: Use a console log to verify if it fetches the video that you want (videoUrl) and try to do it without the autoplay to see if it works first

Comment: If it works try to only write autoplay instead of allow=autoplay

Comment: <video controls (click)="toggleVideo()" #videoPlayer width="640" height="400" controls autoplay>

Comment: I console my function which is this `toggleVideo(event: any) {
    if (this.videoplayer) {
      this.videoplayer.nativeElement.play();
      console.log(this.videoplayer);
    }
    // this.videoplayer.nativeElement.pause();
  }` and i got this in my console... `ElementRef {nativeElement: video}` which means it is there even with or without the autoplay. yet it is still not playing the video

Comment: the event argument inside my toggleVideo(event: any) is not active but i dont know the reason?